# Using $wpdb generates DB error

Tags: wpdb, errors, sql

I'm trying to display content from SQL tables, using `$wpdb` object.
Problem is, whatever I try using it in my query, it prints a SQL error.
What I tried to do is a little more complex than what I'll show you, but I progressively simplified my query to see where the error could come from, but never found.

So here's what I tried last:

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors();
$tableCustom = 'join_users_defis';

$requeteAffichage = $wpdb->get_results('
SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->postmeta
');

var_dump($requeteAffichage);

?>
```

To me, it's supposed to dump the content of the table `{$table_prefix}_postmeta` (I tried with others tables), which is a standard WordPress table. But instead, it outputs the following error (thanks to `$wpdb->show_errors();`):

> WordPress database error : [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near `->_posts` at line 2]

My current installation runs locally (`XAMPP`), with `MariaDB 10.1.16 / Apache / PHP 5.6.24`

To be sure, I tried querying directly with my WordPress installation prefix, and it worked.

Is it an issue with my installation, or something I missed ? I could use some help on this.

Comment: `$wpdb->postmeta` in single quotes is not read as a variable, just as a string. And that table doesn't exist, of course.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Seems like it's a quote issue.
That being said, the table *prefix*_postmeta exists in the WordPress database ;)

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) to know the difference between string representations in PHP. It has explanation about single quote vs. double quote. **Hint:** PHP doesn't replace value of a variable when it is within single quote. So database gets the variable name, not the actual database name inside that variable  `$wpdb->postmeta`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its a syntax error according to error message. starements like below might work for you.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors();
$tableCustom = 'join_users_defis';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}";
$requeteAffichage = $wpdb->get_row( $sql );

//or $requeteAffichage = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

var_dump($requeteAffichage);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you ! It works perfectly.
Is there any explanation that the single quotes output an error when double quotes are fine ?

Comment: actually you placed the variable/object inside single quote which will not print the value of that variable. `$some = 'some'; echo '$some';` is wrong. variable cannot be inside quotation marks. you have to concatenate variable with other statement if you want to use single quote 
`$sql = 'SELECT * FROM'.$wpdb->postmeta};` this will work too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use double quoted string literals for PHP to properly interpret variables in the string. Change:

```
$wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta');
```

to:

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}");
```

Answer (score 1):

`$wpdb->` doesn't belong in the query.

Change

```
$requeteAffichage = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->postmeta
");
```

to

```
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
$postmeta = $prefix . 'postmeta';
$requeteAffichage = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT * 
FROM $postmeta
");
```

(or, if you are using a different table prefix, substitute that prefix for wp_.)

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for answering. In fact I try to make the query usable for other installations, so I need the prefix to be automatically found. But yes, that way it works !

Comment: Updated above to work with any prefix (which also makes it compatible with MultiSite).

Comment: Actually using `$wpdb->postmeta` is a good thing, it covers all possible table prefix set by the site owner. The main problem was single quoted string. Your updated CODE will not work either as `$postmeta` variable will be presented to DB directly (with `$` sign), not its value :)

Comment: Good catch! Updated with double quotes above so it would work.